# Get concatenated list of id's for same product

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
create table Customer (
    custid integer not null,
    prodid integer not null,
    primary key(custid,prodid)
);
```

the values in this table are as follows:

```
Custid |  Prodid

1         10    
1         11    
2         10    
2         11    
3         10    
3         11    
4         11
```

I want to get all those pairs of customers that bought the same products.

My final output should be concantenated list as follows:

```
Custid

1,2    
2,3    
1,3    
1,4    
2,4    
3,4
```

I have written a query as follows:

```
SELECT custid, group_concat(prodid,',')
FROM
    (SELECT UNIQUE custid FROM Customer)
    group by custid;
```

However this gives me:

```
1  10,11    
2  10,11    
3  10,11    
4  11
```

How do I get the pairs of custid's from this? How to write it in subqueries?

Can someone help me in this.

Comment: I'm curious how Oracle syntax returns valid data when you have a mysql tag on the question.  What database are you really using?  In addition, your sample query is incorrect syntactically because `prodid` is not defined.

Comment: What's `LISTAGG`?  That's not a MySQL function.

Comment: Sorry by mistake I posted the Oracle query. It is a MySQL query. I am using GROUP_CONCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, but note that I don't have MySQL access today so it's untested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(a.custid, ',', b.custid)
FROM Customer a
JOIN Customer b ON a.prodid = b.prodid
WHERE a.custid < b.custid
```